# Getting Java IO Exception while connecting to peripheral device over bluetooth

Tags: android, xamarin, bluetooth

I am working on a xamarin android application in which I have to communicate with the RFID reader over bluetooth.

My connection with Peripheral is not through always. It is giving exception - Java.IO.IOException: Exception of type 'Java.IO.IOException' was thrown.

Some times connections is successful but most of the times it is giving above exception.

I am using SPP profile.

Android side BT is - 3.0. Asus Nexus 7 with android version 5.1.1

Peripheral side BT is - 2.1

Anyone has any idea why this is behaving like this? Is there any solution or workaround for this so it could connect every time?

Vishal N

Comment: Did you try to run the app in release mode?  Sometime when we run the application in debug mode causes this kind of exceptions

Comment: Please include the full stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have tested it in release mode and connection problem is observed. Below us the stack trace:

> Stack Trace: Java.IO.IOException: Exception of type
>   'Java.IO.IOException' was thrown.   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallVoidMethod (IntPtr jobject, IntPtr jmethod)
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Android.Bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.Connect () [0x00000] in :0    at Android.Bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.m__0
>   () [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke () [0x00000] in :0    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in
>   :0 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00000] in :0
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00000] in :0
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00000] in :0
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000]
>   in :0